# Xcode: variable dialog on hover not working

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I'm using Xcode 6 (Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)) and I find the dialog that usually pops up when you hover over a variable in Xcode (just before your breakpoint) incredibly useful.

However sometimes this dialog won't appear.
Is this a bug with Xcode or are there reasons why it sometimes won't appear?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same Xcode version.

Assuming:

1. You are not hovering on a property: self.myVar (does not work - not sure why!)
2. You are not hovering on a variable of an instance: cell.myImageView. Hover will only work for cell here.
3. You are not clicked in on the variable - happens by mistake sometimes with the trackpad.

I think it is bug with some peculiar behavior. It seems to happen when you open and close the Navigator or Utilities pane - which is common during debugging. Here is how I was able to replicate it:

1. Set a breakpoint
2. Run
3. Hover on a variable that works
4. Close and open Navigator or Utilities pane
5. Hover on that same variable - it will not work.

This seems to work once. In order to replicate it, you have to run again.

Having said that, if it is not working; if you hover above the variable sideways or up/down or, move away and come back to the variable, it usually will display the variable value.

But i agree, the erratic nature is annoying.

Hope this helps.